# Another hand tiling puzzle - 8 convex shapes from 7 polyiamonds

Tags: no-computers, tiling, polyiamond

Arrange the 7 polyiamonds in the image into 8 different convex shapes. One after the other, not simultaneously... Rotating and flipping allowed. No gaps or overlaps.

Should be a fairly easy puzzle.

[image]

Comment: It took me 4 tries to draw it correctly